# PDO, 'could not find driver' in laravel 7.20.0

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, localhost, wampserver

I have a common problem in my laravel project.When I try to connect laravel with mysql database they say : "could not find driver".
[image: Driver not found]

when I type php -m in cmd to search for php modules installed I can't find mysql,pgsql or sqlite.
please, if you have a solution for this problem answer me, I tried a lot of solutions.
N.B: I use wampSERVER 3.2.0 with mysql 3.8.18 and php 7.4.0

Comment: Which "solutions" did you try so far?

Comment: install the last version of wamp server, the last version of php, the last version of laravel, the last version of mysql, modify the .env file, modify php.init file,php artisan migrate:fresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click WAMPServer icon on system tray then click php.ini under PHP item. next find this lines:

```
;extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=mysqli
```

and change them to these:

```
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=mysqli
```

Then click on Restart All Services in WampServer menu

Comment: hello my friend, thanks for your comment, finally it worked with me after 2 days of trying.I just followed those steps:  
1-in PHP.init I've already changed the two lines you say but in vain.
2-php artisan migrate==> the same question
type in cmd those 2 comands in the same path of your laravel project                                 3-php artisan migrate:fresh
4-php artisan migrate => then it works