# could not find driver in laravel 7 application

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to connect the database with my Laravel 7 application but each time when I hit `php artisan migrate`  I am getting the following errors.

I have connected my .env file as below:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=""
```

Illuminate\Database\QueryException

```
  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = test and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675| 

      +32 vendor frames 
  33  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I have tried several ways including uncommenting an extension in the php.ini file but nothing changed!

Comment: Remove the quotes in password. Just write `DB_PASSWORD=` only

Comment: Yes I did so but it didnt fix the problem :(

Comment: There are already solutions to this. You may see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62972936/pdo-could-not-find-driver-in-laravel-7-20-0  These might help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909397/laravel-5-4-on-php-7-0-pdo-exception-could-not-find-driver-mysql 
Or this

Answer (score 1):

Are you on Linux? If yes you'll have to install the `php-mysql` package if you're on Ubuntu and `php-mysqlnd` package if you're on Fedora.

On Windows and macOS all these stuff come built into WAMP or MAMP or whatever one uses.

Comment: Yes i am using ubuntu. Can you share the command to install php-mysql  ? Thanks a lot

Comment: When I hit `sudo apt-get install php-mysql`, it also shows an error.

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php-mysql : Depends: php7.0-mysql but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: Did you installed php from [Ondřej Surý](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) repository? I would suggest you uninstall your currently installed php and reinstall by executing `sudo apt install php7.4-cli php7.4-json php7.4-xml php7.4-tokenizer php7.4-mysql php7.4-redis php7.4-bcmath php7.4-mbstring` command. This include almost all necessary dependencies for running a vanilla Laravel application.

Comment: Also, if the broken package issue persists, try out the solutions in this [link](https://linuxhint.com/apt_get_fix_missing_broken_packages/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help mate. I have tried all the things but still I couldn't solve the issue. I am sure something is wrong with my php or mysql.